# Choosing the best type of analysis for my variables and objectives

Tags: logistic, log-linear

I am struggling to identify the best analysis for my design. My two independent variables are binary (dichotomous) and my dependent variable is also binary (dichotomous). The goal is to find whether there are differences between the IVs in affecting the DV, and whether there is an interaction between my variables. I need what ANOVA does but I cannot use ANOVA as my DV is dichotomous. I'm not sure if a binary logistic regression is a good fit for my aim? I also worry that I may have to use a loglinear model (logit) analysis (I have seen a paper using it for this type of design) as I am struggling to find tutorials of how to conduct the logit type of loglinear analysis in spss.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is likely from a completely different world than the one you live in, but I would recommend to consider partial information decomposition (PID). It is a rather new development, I have recently written a [publication](https://doi.org/10.1162/netn_a_00259) detailing its application to experimental data.

The idea is that PID splits the information shared by two IVs and one DV into 4 parts: information uniquely shared by each IV, information redundantly shared by both IVs, and information synergistically shared by both IVs. The procedure is rather stable for discrete variables (not yet the case for continuous variables), and should be straightforward to apply to your case. For example, consider the [IDTxl](https://github.com/pwollstadt/IDTxl) library in Python.

In simple terms, your IVs can have independent predictive power over the DV (called unique in PID), shared or redundant predictive power over the DV, and can also interact synergistically, such that predictive power of both IVs taken together is greater than that of individual IVs. A great example of such synergistic interaction is the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) function. It is easy to observe that for XOR both IVs are completely uncorrelated to the DV, but taken together they completely determine the DV.

Comment: thank you for all this, I will look into it and your publication. I might not be smart enough for this! Is it possible to do it in matlab?

Comment: @lisaarthur sadly I am not aware of matlab implementations. I don't believe that people are fundamentally smart or dumb. It is mostly about passion, priorities and the amount of time you can/wish to dedicate to a certain subject. Python is not rocket science. It takes 2 lines of code to read in a data file and another 2-3 lines to call the PID routine from the library. PID itself is somewhat intricate, but you don't have to understand how it works, you just need to know what it aims to calculate

Answer (score 0):

Binary logistic regression should be fine (basically, ANOVA is linear regression on categorical dummy variables, and what you have is a logistic regression of this kind, at least if model assumptions are OK).

There is no specific distinction between IV and DV in loglinear models, although I think this could probably also be applied here. It would require some thought about what exactly to test, so "out of the box" I'd prefer the logistic regression.

Comment: Thank you so much, this gives me confidence to go with logistic for that design. I also have two mediator variables; would I be able to add them to the logistic regression or would that be separate analyses? I want to see whether each mediator mediates the effect of each IV on the DV. And final question; if my IVs are dichotomous and my DV is an ordinal (I think) variable measured on a Likert scale (only with one question and with options from 1 [the least] to 10 [the most]), is that ordinal regression? Thank you so much.

Comment: @lisaarthur Mediators: I don't have much experience with mediation analysis. I suspect yes but am not sure. Ordinal regression should be OK with an ordinal DV, once more provided model assumptions are fine.

Comment: thank you so much again. I'm just looking into logistic regression. My problem is that it just predicts which IV explains the DV the best and some odds ratios whilst what I need is what anova does. I would like to know if there is an interaction between my factors (IVs) and "the degree to which one factor is differentially effective at each level of a second factor". Whether the type of images that my participants were exposed to affected their altruistic behaviours + whether their gender had anything to do with it. Logistic regression does not seem fitting :(

Comment: @lisaarthur You can include an interaction factor in your model, and then compare the models with and without interaction using a likelihood ratio/deviance test.